# How can you display an ImageView in a consistent way on the right side of differing horizontal LinearLayouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that uses vertical LinearLayouts nested within horizontal LinearLayouts in order to blocks for the user to click on. The issue I am having is that I can get the arrow icons on the right side to line up perfectly, but when I change the screen size in Android Studio, the arrow in the top LinearLayout gets misaligned. I have tried adjusting the gravity for the arrow icons, setting layout margins, and setting specific widths to the layout versus using match_parent and wrap_content. I just can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code for the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Settings">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/name"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,DuplicateSpeakableTextCheck" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llUserProfileEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/user_icon"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:foregroundTint="@color/yellow"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
            app:tint="@color/yellow"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/replaceWithUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/user_s_name"
                android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editProfileLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/arrow_right_icon"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/name2"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDeleteAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="311dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelDeleteAccount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:text="@string/delete_your_account"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.FeederDriver"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelRemoveAccountSubtext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:text="@string/permanently_remove_your_data1"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/arrow_right_icon"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/name1"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llAbout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="312dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAbout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:text="@string/about"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.FeederDriver"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelAbout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:text="@string/view_information_about_this_app"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/arrow_right_icon"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/divider3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/name1"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLogout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSubLogout"
            android:layout_width="312dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLogout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:text="@string/logout"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.FeederDriver"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelLogout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:text="@string/logout_securely"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/arrow_right_icon"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_ios_24" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/divider4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/name1"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[Here's what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIeF9.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is long and old process for build layout . I will suggest to use [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) for build layout in Android.

Comment: Do you know how I could attach a single onClickListener to a group of objects (ex. TextView and ImageView) using constraint layout?